# Python SimpleHTTP Server rfile.readlines() taking long time

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, httpserver

I have a simple HTTP server having a do_POST method for uploading image file.

```
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        data = self.rfile.readlines()
```

Its taking long time for reading the image binary data. How can I make it read the image data faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution for reading whole incoming binary data.

```
data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
```

Where **Content-Length** entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, (**Note:** remember to convert the `content-length` type into `int` before passing it into `read()`)